# Inner poll gender analytics

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to get **gender statistics** of profiles responding to my asking question in a group?
And what another analytic features does it (poll) have?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has virtually no analytics from asking a question In a group other than results from the poll

Comment: Does it mean there is no way to get any stat of some opened profile (who answered on question) properties like age and others?